# I can't get rid of the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: web3js is not defined"

Tags: web3js, metamask, error

I've been trying to get rid of this error, but no matter how much I try, I just can't figure this out. I've finished the tutorials of cryptoZombies, and all I know about web3 I got from there. 
I created the simplest app possible to show the error I'm getting. This is my contract, deployed on Ropsten:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract SimpleRegister {
   string name;

   function setName(string _name) external {
      name = _name;
   }

   function getName() external view returns (string) {
      return (name);
   }
}
```

My frontend is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Document</title>

   <script src="./web3.min.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="abi.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
   <h1>Simple Register</h1>
   <h2 id="display"></h2>     
   <button type="submit" onclick="getName();return false;">Get Name</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {  
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {     
            web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider); 
        } 
        else {
            this.alert("Install Metamask.");         
        }
        startApp();
    });

    function startApp() {
        var contractAddress = "0x715e99e73deefdb06f9d1e55172cbc52307eda5b";   
        simpleRegister = new web3js.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
    }

    function _getName() {
        return simpleRegister.methods.getName().call();
    }

    function getName() {           
        _getName().then(function(result) {
            $("#display").html(result[0]);
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone has an idea about what's going on and how to fix that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just open the html file and have MetaMask inject it's web3 instance in.

From the MetaMask [documentation](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md):

> Due to browser security restrictions, we can't communicate with dapps running on file://. Please use a local server for development.

The easiest way round this is to use Python's SimpleHTTPServer from the project root directory:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

You can then visit http://localhost:8000 in the web browser with MetaMask extension installed.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code there is small mistake, in your code.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {  
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {     
            web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider); 
        } 
        else {
            this.alert("Install Metamask.");  
            return;
        }
        startApp();
    });

    function startApp() {
        var contractAddress = "0x715e99e73deefdb06f9d1e55172cbc52307eda5b";   
        simpleRegister = new web3js.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
    }

    function _getName() {
        return simpleRegister.methods.getName().call();
    }

    function getName() {           
        _getName().then(function(result) {
            $("#display").html(result[0]);
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
</script>
```

If metamask is not found still your calling web3js startApp(). As per your code if metamask is not found then web3js is undefined, in web3js is undefined.

Comment: Absolutely, if there is no injected web3 you'd usually fallback to a local web3 instance connected to a node e.g. Infura. See: https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you actually have the file **web3.min.js** in the same folder as that HTML code you have.

You can download a copy from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases) (note: it will be in the /dist folder).

Comment: Thank you, but I already had the file in the same folder. I downloaded from the link you sent as well (maybe the one I used before was broken), but it didn't work as well.